# How to split csv file into multiple files by size

Tags: java, file, csv, split, size

in a java project i generate a big csv file (about 500 Mb), and i need to split that file into multiple files of at most 10 Mb size each one.
I found a lot of posts similar but any of them answer to my question because in all posts the java code split the original files in exactly 10 Mb files, and (obviously) truncate records.
Instead i need each record is complete, intact.
Any record should be truncated.
If i'm copying a record from the original big csv file to one generated file, and the file dimension will overflow 10 Mb if i copy the record, i should be able to not copy that record, close that file, create a new file and copy the record in the new one.
Is it possible?
Can someone help me?
Thank you!

I tried this code:

```
File f = new File("/home/luca/Desktop/test/images.csv");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
FileOutputStream out;
String name = f.getName();
int partCounter = 1;
int sizeOfFiles = 10 * 1024 * 1024;// 1MB
byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];
int tmp = 0;
while ((tmp = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
 File newFile=new File("/home/luca/Desktop/test/"+name+"."+String.format("%03d", partCounter++));
 newFile.createNewFile();
 out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
 out.write(buffer,0,tmp);
 out.close();
}
```

But obviously doesn't work.
This code split a source file in n 10Mb files truncating records. 
In my case my csv file has 16 columns so with the procedure above i have for example the last record has only 5 columns populated. The others are truncated.

**SOLUTION**
Here the code i wrote.

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("/home/luca/Desktop/test/images.csv");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String line="";
int fileSize = 0;
BufferedWriter fos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/luca/Desktop/test/images_"+new Date().getTime()+".csv",true));
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(fileSize + line.getBytes().length > 9.5 * 1024 * 1024){
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        fos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/luca/Desktop/test/images_"+new Date().getTime()+".csv",true));
        fos.write(line+"\n");
        fileSize = line.getBytes().length;
    }else{
        fos.write(line+"\n");
        fileSize += line.getBytes().length;
    }
}          
fos.flush();
fos.close();
bufferedReader.close();
```

This code read a csv file and split it to n files, each file is at most 10 Mb big and each csv line is completely copied or not copied at all.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  If you just want someone to write the program for you, you need to hire a programmer.

Comment: Its good SPEC for freelancer.

Comment: There is no reason to answer so rudely and i'm not a freelances.

Comment: I know how you feel right now but you have to understand no one will start to write code based on a general "i need that and this and that" requirement. As soon as you have code and youre stuck at a certain point people here will help you. As for now i think its already unclear if you want to create sperate files the time you create the very large file or if you want to split an existing file into multpile parts. I personaly also dont understand if you want to have things split to exactly 10Mb or have a specific structure ("record") per file. Please provide further information and code.

Comment: Ok, thank. I have the csv big file from another procedure. So i can only work on this file after it is generated. Each csv line has 16 columns. And the desiderable outcome is a group of files with a dimension the closest possibile to 10 Mb, and each file should contains only complete records (each csv line should have the 16 columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle very simple.

You create a buffer of 10MB (byte[]) and read as many bytes as you can from the source. Then you search from the *back* for a line feed. The portion from the beginning of the buffer to the line feed = new file. You retain the part you have read in excess and copy it to start of buffer (offset 0). The you repeat everything until no more source.

Comment: Thank you. I added also the solution.

Answer (score 0):

use this `split -a 3 -b 100m -d filename.tar.gz  newfilename`

Comment: This truncates the individual record at the end of each  split file.

Answer (score 0):

This will split any line based file including CSV's into a file within (line length - 1) of the specified size. It will repeat the header row is specified (such as for CSV's with a header row):

```
protected void processDocument(File inFile, long maxFileSize, boolean containsHeaderRow) {       
    if (maxFileSize > 0 && infile.length() > maxFileSize) {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        try {
            byte[] headerRow = new byte[0];
            if (containsHeaderRow) {
                try {
                    String headerLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if (headerLine != null) {
                        headerRow = (headerLine + "\n").getBytes();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to read header row from input file.", e1);
                }
            }
            long headerRowByteCount = headerRow.length;
            if (maxFileSize < headerRowByteCount) {
                // Would just write header repeatedly so throw error
                throw new Exception("Split file size is less than the header row size.");
            }
            int fileCount = 0;
            boolean notEof = true;
            while (notEof) {
                fileCount += 1;
                long fileSize = 0;
                // create a new file with same path but appended count
                String newFilename = inFile.getAbsolutePath() |+ "-" + fileCount;
                File outFile = new File(newFilename);
                BufferedOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    try {
                        fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new Exception("Failed to initialise output file for file splitting on file " + fileCount, e);
                    }
                    if (containsHeaderRow) {
                        try {
                            fos.write(headerRow);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to write header row to output file for file splitting on file " + fileCount, e);
                        }
                        fileSize += headerRowByteCount;
                    }
                    while (fileSize < maxFileSize) {
                        String line = null;
                        try {
                            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to write output file for file splitting on file " + fileCount, e);
                        }
                        if (line == null) {
                            notEof = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        byte[] lineBytes = (line + "\n").getBytes();
                        fos.write(lineBytes);
                        fileSize += lineBytes.length;
                    }
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    processDocument(outFile); 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to write output file for file splitting on file number" + fileCount, e);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (fos != null) {
                            fos.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Exception("Failed to close reader for input file.", e);
            }
        }

    } else {
        processDocument(inFile); 
    }
}
```